# How to open all found files in Vim using FuzzyFinder?

Tags: vim, gvim

How do I open all files found by a partial search using FuzzyFinder?

For example, if I type in Directory>.php, it finds all the php files in the directory, but how can I open them all at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use FuzzyFinder to do this, but you could put all the PHP files in Directory in your args list by executing

```
:args Directory/*.php
```

and then open all the files in the args list with

```
:all
```

See

```
:help :args
:help :all
```

You might find the following useful as well.

```
:help wildcard
:help starstar-wildcard
:help starstar
:help 07.2
```